# Динамическое меню

Tags: php, база-данных, sql

Есть один урок по созданию динамической генерации страниц ([ссылка](http://www.pikalov.kiev.ua/?p=39&cpage=2#comment-341014)). Но там не говорится как сделать что бы эти страницы брались из БД. Вопрос: куда засунуть sql запрос на выборку ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный способ построения HTML-страниц основан на шаблонизации. Это такой способ, когда страница строится из различных данных( стилей, HTML, JS, PHP кода и т.д ), которые, в свою очередь, берутся из базы данных. Это очень хороший способ построения, так как верстальщики, например, имеют доступ только к стилям и html-коду, не путаясь в неизвестном им PHP и, возможно, JS. С разработчиками самого функционала такая же картина.